# Not able to access iPod library path

Tags: iphone, audio, ipod, mpmusicplayercontroller

I am using Media Player Framework and its MPMusicPlayer controller for integration with iPhone's default player. I got the asset URL as :- 
**ipod-library://item/item.mp3?id=4157200259458444598**
Now I need to access this URL for copying this song to my application's 'song.mp3' file. Can anyone please help me to access the iPod URL so that I can use it in my iPhone app as the way I want.
Any quick help is really appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Apple do not allow you to copy the contents of the iPod library out to your user area. This is to prevent copyright infringement. If you want to just play the song then you'll need to post a more detailed question.

Comment: My purpose is to make beats (visualizer) of the song played using the 'Speak Here' app (http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#samplecode/SpeakHere/Introduction/Intro.html). I have changed the code to take my song URL instead of speaking/recording. Beats and visualizer is working fine. with that song (existing in the app). But now my purpose is to use song running in default iTunes player in my iPhone. I can access the song from MPMedia player framework but its asset URL is not generating beats.I need to copy that asset URL to my application .mp3 file.Please propose some solution urgently.

Comment: I would also appreciate if some one has internal player example which generates music beats(visualizer) which I can use in my application?